# How to increase element's width automatically when the scrollbar appears?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm making a mini sidebar when users decreases their browser's width. I'm getting stuck when I work with `height` css property. I allow users to scroll the sidebar.

But I don't know how to increase the sidebar's width automatically when the vertically scrollbar appears.

```css
/* START - bootstrap */
.list-unstyled {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.m-auto {
  margin: auto;
}

.text-light {
  color: rgb(248, 249, 250);
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.p-3 {
  padding: 1rem!important;
}
/* END - bootstrap */

.sidebar-medium {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff758c 0%, #ff7eb3 100%);
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.avatar {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 90% 20%, 100% 60%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 60%, 10% 20%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="shadow-sm text-light sidebar-medium">
    <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
        <li class="text-center p-3">
            <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto avatar" style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jv5C.jpg?s=328&g=1');"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center p-3">
            <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center p-3">
            <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-radiation"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center p-3">
            <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-history"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center p-3">
            <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center p-3">
            <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center p-3">
            <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center p-3">
            <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center p-3">
            <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center p-3">
            <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-cogs"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Screenshot (With and without the scrollbar):

[image: 1]

How can I increase the sidebar's width automatically in this case (without javascript)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to query the `height`.

```
@media (max-height: 570px) { /* this is when the scrollbar appears */
    .sidebar-medium {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

```css
.list-unstyled {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.m-auto {
  margin: auto;
}

.text-light {
  color: rgb(248, 249, 250);
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.p-3 {
  padding: 1rem !important;
}


/* END - bootstrap */

.sidebar-medium {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff758c 0%, #ff7eb3 100%);
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.avatar {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  clip-path: polygon( 50% 0%, 90% 20%, 100% 60%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 60%, 10% 20%);
}

@media (max-height: 570px) {
  .sidebar-medium {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="shadow-sm text-light sidebar-medium">
  <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto avatar" style="
              background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jv5C.jpg?s=328&g=1');
            "></div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-radiation"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-history"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-cogs"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `transition` for better effect. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the `::-webkit-scrollbar` in order to have a better visual :

```css
/* START - bootstrap */

.list-unstyled {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.m-auto {
  margin: auto;
}

.text-light {
  color: rgb(248, 249, 250);
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.p-3 {
  padding: 1rem !important;
}


/* END - bootstrap */

.sidebar-medium {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff758c 0%, #ff7eb3 100%);
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.avatar {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 90% 20%, 100% 60%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 60%, 10% 20%);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 2px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="shadow-sm text-light sidebar-medium">
  <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto avatar" style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jv5C.jpg?s=328&g=1');"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-radiation"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-history"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-3">
      <div class="align-self-center d-inline-block m-auto text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-cogs"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But from [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar): `This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.` I'm looking for a better solution but thanks!